# Digitally sign a Visual Studio 2012 VSIX extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, digital-signature, vsix

I am trying to sign a `Visual Studio 2012 extension` that is packaged as a `VSIX` file.

I have followed the instructions at http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/vsixcodesigning/; however, I am  interested in performing signing without specifying a pfx file and password.

For example, if I were to call 'signtool.exe', my command line would be:

```
"signtool.exe" sign /n MySubjectName /t 'http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll' /d "MyDescription" MyPackage.vsix
```

I understand that this command does not work with `VSIX` files, though it does work for an `MSI` archive.

With this command, I do not need to specify a password or pfx file when calling signtool. The best installed certificate is selected, using the specified subject `MySubjectName`.

Following the code on [Jeff's Blog](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/vsixcodesigning/), the signing step requires pfx file name and password to be defined to create the `X509Certificate2` used in signing:

```
 private static void SignAllParts(Package package, string pfx, string password, string timestamp){
  var signatureManager = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
  signatureManager.CertificateOption = CertificateEmbeddingOption.InSignaturePart;

  /*...*/

  signatureManager.Sign(toSign, new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(pfx, password));
}
```

Is there any API involving `PackageDigitalSignatureManager` that might let me find a `X509Certificate` based on `MySubjectName` so that I can sign against that?

Comment: This may contain the answer that I am looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find.aspx

Comment: There isn't such API, to get certificate by the Subject Name. But you can look at the Import method of X509Certificate2 class.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by iterating over the certificates found in the current user's store. I filter by the issuer name and take only valid certificates, then I loop over the matching certificates and return the first one which matches also the subject name:

```
public static X509Certificate2 Find(string issuer, string subject)
{
    var certStore = new X509Store (StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open (OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find (X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, issuer, true);

    foreach (var cert in certCollection)
    {
        if (cert.FriendlyName == subject)
        {
            return cert;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```